# filter item with checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I just want to make a filter with checkbox array using jquery and javascript. It works fine when only one checkbox is selected but when I select two or more checkboxes it doesn't show all the divs. Could you please help me to find my mistake.
I want to filter through the filter array. The name of our array is FlyList

```js
let FlyList = [
  {
    id: "1",
    Airline_number: "961",
    Type_ticket: "systemi",
    Airline: "dubai",
    fly_time: "04:00-08:00",
    Class_type: "Economical"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    Airline_number: "962",
    Type_ticket: "charteri",
    Airline: "frans",
    fly_time: "08:00-11:00",
    Class_type: "Commercial"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    Airline_number: "963",
    Type_ticket: "systemi",
    Airline: "Emirates",
    fly_time: "11:00-14:00",
    Class_type: "Commercial"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    Airline_number: "964",
    Type_ticket: "systemi",
    Airline: "Emirates",
    fly_time: "14:00-17:00",
    Class_type: "Economical"
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    Airline_number: "965",
    Type_ticket: "charteri",
    Airline: "dubai",
    fly_time: "17:00-21:00",
    Class_type: "Commercial"
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    Airline_number: "966",
    Type_ticket: "charteri",
    Airline: "frans",
    fly_time: "21:00-24:00",
    Class_type: "Economical"
  }
];

function customFilter(list, field, value) {
  let fill = list.filter(item => {
    if (typeof filter === "object") {
      value.forEach(val => {
        return item[field] === value;
      });
    }
  });
  console.log(fill);
}

let filterCheckbox = document.querySelector(".customCheck");
filterCheckbox.addEventListener("change", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // jquery
  // var field = $(this).parents('.filter_type').attr('data-field');
  let field = document.querySelector(".filter_type").getAttribute("data-field");
  // jquery

  let val = e.target.value;

  customFilter(FlyList, field, val);
  // console.log(val);
});

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="filters">
  <div class="collapse show" id="collapseFilters">
    <div class="filter_type" data-field="Type_ticket">
      <h6>
        Type of ticket
        <div class="switcher float-left ">
          <label class="customToggle small">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" class="selectall" />
            all Type of ticket
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </h6>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck w-100 " id="filter-check">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="systemi" class="individual" />
            systemi
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck w-100" id="filter-check2">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name=""
              value="charteri"
              class="individual"
            />
            charteri
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_type airlineSelection" data-field="Airline">
      <h6>
        airline
        <div class="switcher float-left">
          <label class="customToggle small">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
            all airline
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </h6>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck" id="">
            <input type="checkbox" value="frans" name="inlineRadioOptions" />
            frans
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" name="inlineRadioOptions" /> dubai
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="emirates" name="inlineRadioOptions" />
            emirates
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="frans" name="inlineRadioOptions" />
            frans
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="emirates" name="inlineRadioOptions" />
            emirates
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input type="checkbox" value="dubai" name="inlineRadioOptions" />
            dubai
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="filter_type" data-field="Class_type">
      <h6>
        Class_type
        <div class="switcher float-left">
          <label class="customToggle small">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
            all Class_type
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </h6>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck" id="">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="economical"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            economical
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="commercial"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            commercial
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter_type" data-field="fly_time">
      <h6>
        fly_time
        <div class="switcher float-left">
          <label class="customToggle small">
            <input type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
            all fly_time
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </h6>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck" id="">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="04:00-08:00"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            04:00-08:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="08:00-11:00"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            08:00-11:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="11:00-14:00"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            11:00-14:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="14:00-17:00"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            14:00-17:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="17:00-21:00"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            17:00-21:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="customCheck">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="21:00-24:00"
              name="inlineRadioOptions"
            />
            21:00-24:00
            <div class="indicator"></div>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

With [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) you select only one element. That's why you add an event listener to only first `.customCheck` checkbox.

You need to have an event listener attached to all the checkboxes. To do so you can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead of `querySelector` and then attach an event to each input:

```
let filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.customCheck');

filterCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox => checkbox.addEventListener('change' , (e) => { 
  console.log(e);
  // filtering goes here
}))
```

Comment: We want when ckechbox is clicked. Display information about it. And other boxes to hide.And when unchecked. Return to the first state